# Easy continuous probability question.

Tags: probability

If a real number $x$ is chosen at random in the interval $[0,3]$ and a real number $y$ is chosen at random in the interval $[0,4]$, what is the probability that $x<y$?

I thought this problem would be as easy as simply halving the area of the rectangle $[0,3]\times[0,4] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and dividing it by $12$, so the answer would be $1/2$, but the answer key says it is $5/8$. How do you solve this?

Note: I never had exposure to a proper probability class. I have noticed that the math subject GRE test's probability part level is fairly easy, and I'm taking it in October. What is a good website where I can learn basic continuous probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle of interest is *not* fully half the area of the rectangle.  It is only a corner made from one side, and part way up another (3/4 the way to be precise), and cut from there to there.

It's the area within the $[0,3]\times[0,4]$ rectangle that lies below the line $Y=X$.   Thus represents $Y<X$.

Compare the areas.

$\lVert\triangle (0,0)(3,0)(3,3)\rVert = \tfrac 1 2 \cdot 3^3$

$\Vert\Box(0,0)(3,0)(3,4)(0,4)\rVert = 3\cdot 4$

Since we actually want the probability of $X\geq Y$, we use the law of complements.   (This is slightly easier than calculating the area of the trapezoid.)

$$\text{Thus} :\Bbb P(X<Y) = 1-\frac{3}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

The possible pairs $(x,y)$ exist anywhere within the rectangle that you have described. The points that obey the restriction $x<y$ lie to the left and above the straight line with equation $y=x$. This gives a trapezium whose area can be calculated, but it is easier to calculate the area of the triangle representing $x>y$. This has area $\frac {3 \times 3} 2 = 4.5$ unit$^2$. The big rectangle has area $12$ unit$^2$, so the trapezium is $7.5$ unit$^2$. Divide that by $12$ to get the probability. $\frac {7.5}{12}=\frac {15}{24}=\frac {5}{8} $ as required.